# Error with Enum.GetNames()

Tags: c#, enums

When I try and compile this code,
I get this error.

Error 1 The type or namespace name 'transmission' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How will I be able to rectify this error?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
public enum transmission
{
    Manual,
    NonSynchronous,
    Automatic,
    SemiAutomatic,
    Continuously,
    Infinitely,
    Electric,
    Hydrostatic,
    Hydrodynamic,
   }

}
    public class Car
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] transmissions = Enum.GetNames(typeof(transmission));

        foreach(String transmission in transmissions) {
            Console.WriteLine(transmission);
        }


    }
 }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are outside the scope of `ConsoleApplication1` namespace. Either include `Car` class to that namespace or call `typeof(ConsoleApplication1.transmission)`.